# Convert &str to f64 using a Rust Polars custom function

Tags: dataframe, rust, rust-polars

My problem can probably be described as being very new to both Rust and Polars. Go easy on me. :)

I'm trying to establish a pattern using custom functions, based on this documentation: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/custom_functions.html, however am so far unsuccessful.

In my code, I have a function declared as follows:

```
pub fn convert_str_to_tb(value: &str) -> f64 {
    let value = value.replace(",", "");
    let mut parts = value.split_whitespace();
    let num = parts.next().unwrap().parse::<f64>().unwrap();
    let unit = parts.next().unwrap();

    match unit {
        "KB" => num / (1000.0 * 1000.0 * 1000.0),
        "MB" => num / (1000.0 * 1000.0),
        "GB" => num / 1000.0,
        "TB" => num,
        _ => panic!("Unsupported unit: {}", unit),
    }
}
```

I believe I should be able to call this function like so:

```
df.with_columns([
    col("value").map(|s| Ok(convert_str_to_tb(s))).alias("value_tb");
])
```

My first issue was that with_columns method doesn't seem to exist - I had to use with_column. If I use the with_column, I receive the following error:

```
the trait bound `Expr: IntoSeries` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `IntoSeries`:
  Arc<(dyn polars::prelude::SeriesTrait + 'static)>
  ChunkedArray<T>
  Logical<DateType, Int32Type>
  Logical<DatetimeType, Int64Type>
  Logical<DurationType, Int64Type>
  Logical<TimeType, Int64Type>
  polars::prelude::SeriesrustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
```

The DataFrame I am trying to transform:

```
let mut df = df!("volume" => &["volume01", "volume02", "volume03"],
                 "value" => &["1,000 GB", "2,000,000 MB", "3 TB"]).unwrap();
```

Perhaps there is a way to do this without a custom function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1, with_columns**

One confusing note that should be made about the documentation - the `df` in the example is a lazy data frame. You can see they call `.lazy()` in the full code snippet where a custom function is used. `.with_columns()` is an available method on the lazy data frame.

**Problem 2, custom function**

You have some typing issues around what is expected in the custom function and what you have defined. You are expecting a str input and outputting a f64.  However, as the error implies the `s` parameter is actually a `Series` and the expectation is that the returned value is an `Option<Series>`.

So what's happening here? The `.map()` function is providing you with a series that your custom function needs to iterate over.

Updating your custom function to have the appropriate arg and return type:

```
pub fn convert_str_to_tb(value: Series) -> Option<Series> {
    Some(value.iter().map(|v| {
        let value = v.get_str().unwrap().replace(",", "");
        let mut parts = value.split_whitespace();
        let num = parts.next().unwrap().parse::<f64>().unwrap();
        let unit = parts.next().unwrap();

        match unit {
            "KB" => num / (1000.0 * 1000.0 * 1000.0),
            "MB" => num / (1000.0 * 1000.0),
            "GB" => num / 1000.0,
            "TB" => num,
            _ => panic!("Unsupported unit: {}", unit),
        }
    }).collect())
}
```

And called using

```
df.lazy().with_columns([
    col("value").map(|s| Ok(convert_str_to_tb(s)), GetOutput::default()).alias("value_tb")
]).collect().unwrap();
```

Gives the output:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────────┬──────────┐
│ volume   ┆ value        ┆ value_tb │
│ ---      ┆ ---          ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str          ┆ f64      │
╞══════════╪══════════════╪══════════╡
│ volume01 ┆ 1,000 GB     ┆ 1.0      │
│ volume02 ┆ 2,000,000 MB ┆ 2.0      │
│ volume03 ┆ 3 TB         ┆ 3.0      │
└──────────┴──────────────┴──────────┘
```